# Why does the program fail to load?

Tags: python

I was told that a main() function needs to be put into my code to prevent bugs and ensure the smoothness of the program. However upon loading my game quits when the first board appears.

If I have missed anything out (future potential bugs) I'd like to know.

In future I also plan on putting this game on a website using flask, with the player using the arrow keys to select the location he/she wants to hit before pressing the space bar for the action. If someone could give me an idea on how to begin with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

The program is a console-based 2-player battleships ships game in python:

```
from random import randint

game_board = []
player_one = {
    "name": "Player 1",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}
player_two = {
    "name": "Player 2",
    "wins": 0,
    "lose": 0
}
total_turns = 0

# Building our 5 x 5 board
def build_game_board(board):
    for item in range(5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

def show_board(board):
    print("Find and sink the ship!")
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

# Defining ships locations
def load_game(board):
    print("WELCOME TO BATTLESHIP!")
    print("START")
    del board[:]
    build_game_board(board)
    show_board(board)
    ship_col = randint(1, len(board))
    ship_row = randint(1, len(board[0]))
    return {
        'ship_col': ship_col,
        'ship_row': ship_row,
    }

ship_points = load_game(game_board)

# Players will alternate turns.
def player_turns():
    if total_turns % 2 == 0:
        return player_two

    else:
        return player_one

# Allows new game to start
def play_again():
    answer = input("Would you like to play again?")
    if answer == "yes" or answer == "y":
        total_turns = 0
        ship_points = load_game(game_board)

    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()

# What will be done with players guesses
def input_check(ship_row, ship_col, player, board):
    guess_col = 0
    guess_row = 0
    while True:
        try:
            guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:")) - 1
            guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:")) - 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number only.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    match = guess_row == ship_row - 1 and guess_col == ship_col - 1
    not_on_game_board = (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4)

    if match:
        player["wins"] += 1
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        play_again()

    elif not match:
        if not_on_game_board:
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

        elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X":
            print("You guessed that one already.")

        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        show_board(game_board)

    else:
        return 0


def main():
    begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin.')
    while (begin != str('start')):
        begin = input('Type \'start\' to begin.')
    for games in range(3):
        for turns in range(6):
            total_turns += 1
            if player_turns() == player_one:
                print("Player One")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_one, game_board
                )

            elif player_turns() == player_two:
                print("Player Two")
                input_check(
                    ship_points['ship_row'],
                    ship_points['ship_col'],
                    player_two, game_board
                )

            else:
                continue

            if total_turns == 6:
                print("The game is a draw")
                play_again()

            else:
                continue

if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Comment: What is your **question**?

Comment: Why does the game quit?

Answer (score 3):

Change to the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: But this isn't your only problem `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total_turns' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Comment: @moritzg To fix that I put the variable into the main function. so total_turns=0 is right before the incrementation begins.